# How to link document to different structured template

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word, office-interop

I am try to automate a process for changing the document templates of word files.

If the templates are similar structure, ie they both use `heading1`, then when the document is linked to the new template, it works.

However, the template structure is completely different, `heading1` is no longer used, it is now `section1`. How can I change these section titles with code? Something along the lines of `if(heading1) rename to section1;`

I am using `Interop.Word` to perform these operations.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
public string UpdateDocumentWithNewTemplate(string document, string theme, string template, Word.Application wordApp)
        {
            try
            {
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Word.Document aDoc = null;
                object notReadOnly = false;
                object isVisible = false;
                wordApp.Visible = false;
                // create objects from variables for wordApp
                object documentObject = document;

                // open existing document
                aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref documentObject, ref missing, ref notReadOnly, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                aDoc.Activate();

                // set template and theme to overwrite the existing styles
                aDoc.CopyStylesFromTemplate(template);
                aDoc.ApplyDocumentTheme(theme);
                aDoc.UpdateStyles();

                // save the file with the changes
                aDoc.SaveAs(ref documentObject, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // close the document
                aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                if (aDoc != null)
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aDoc);
                aDoc = null;

                return documentObject.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return "Error: " + exception;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example you need to first import the styles from the other template, then do a Find/Replace to replace the styles applied. I see from your code that you've got the first part (`aDoc.CopyStylesFromTemplate(template); aDoc.ApplyDocumentTheme(theme); aDoc.UpdateStyles();`).

What many don't realize about Word's Find/Replace functionality is that it can also work with formatting. The best way to get the necessary syntax is to record a successful Find/Replace in a macro, then port the VBA to C#. In the UI:

1. Ctrl+H to open the Replace dialog box
2. With the cursor in the "Find what" box, click "More" then "Format" and choose "Style"
3. Select the name of the style you want to find and have replaced
4. Click in the "Replace with" box
5. Use Format/Style, again, to choose the style you want to use
6. Click "Replace All".

[image]

Here's the result I get:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.styles("Heading 1")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.styles("section2")
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .CorrectHangulEndings = False
    .HanjaPhoneticHangul = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

You should use Range, not Selection. So the C# code would look something like the following code block. Note how

1. I get the Range of the entire document
2. Create a `Find` object for the Range and use that
3. To reference Styles for the Find; I show two possibilities
4. You can list almost all the properties for Find before using `Find.Execute`. It would also be possible to create `object` objects for each of these, with only one necessary for `true` and `false` then list these "by ref" in `Find.Execute`. As far as I know, this is simply a matter of personal preference. I did it this way to the most literal "translation" of the VBA to C# code.
5. In any case, `Find.Execute` "remembers" these settings, so `ref missing` can then be used for all the parameters you don't set specifically. In this case, only the "replace all" command is used specifically in the method.

   ```
       Word.Document doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
       Word.Range rngFind = doc.Content;
       Word.Find fd = rngFind.Find;
       fd.ClearFormatting();
       Word.Style stylFind = doc.Styles["Heading 1"];
       fd.set_Style(stylFind);
       fd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
       fd.Replacement.set_Style(doc.Styles["section2"]);
       fd.Text = "";
       fd.Replacement.Text = "";
       fd.Forward = true;
       fd.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
       fd.Format = true;
       fd.MatchCase = false;
       fd.MatchWholeWord = false;
       fd.MatchByte = false;
       fd.CorrectHangulEndings = false;
       fd.HanjaPhoneticHangul = false;
       fd.MatchWildcards = false;
       fd.MatchSoundsLike = false;
       fd.MatchAllWordForms = false;
       object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
       object missing = Type.Missing;
       fd.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
           ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Is it bad practice to use OpenXml as well as Interop? When using Interop I can't seem to remove/apply the headers with it.

Comment: You can use what works :-) Does my code (adjusted for your situation) not work, then? It did work in my tests, before I posted. Is the document protected in any way?

Comment: I don't know what was wrong, didn't seem to be protected but we do use share drives and share point, in the end I just created a new document and copy/format pasted the content of the original into the new one, then applied the template. I tested your code and it works =) and I'm going to integrate it later into the new build.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed - perhaps the original file was damaged internally; not badly enough that Word couldn't open it, but such that changing the style wasn't being accepted. Damaged files can be really... weird.